# vim: Line wrapping after erasing parts of line

Tags: vim, macvim

Suppose I have the text:

```
The quick brown
fox jumps over
the lazy dog.
```

Where I have used a maximum linewidth of 15 characters.
Then, I want to replace "fox jumps over" with "and", i.e., I get:

```
The quick brown 
and
the lazy dog.
```

How I can fixed again my line-wrapping, i.e.,

```
The quick brown 
and the lazy 
dog.
```

**Is there a "fast" way for doing this ?**

Comment: `gqip` ? minimum character filler spam

Comment: This will violate the linewidth limit

Comment: No, it won't. Try it.

Comment: What qualifies as "_fast_"?  You can just hit "J" (capital 'j'), which will join the next line with the one you're on.  Conveniently, you just typed "_and_", so you just (exit insert mode and) hit "J".  For more text which is ragged you can use Visual mode to select desired text  -- then hit a shortcut (`:gq` for example), or invoke `:!fmt -90` (or whatever width you wish), for custom width.